# Reading property file in windows batch with repeating values for a key

Tags: windows, batch-file, readfile

My first attempt to automate some directory creation using a windows batch.

I have file that looks like this:

```
app=application
proj=project
file=file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
app=application2
proj=project2
file=file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I want to read the file so that for each app and project combination, I want to create some directories and copy the files.

Such that in the end I have something like this:

- C:\application\project\file1.txt
- C:\application\project\file2.txt
- C:\application\project\file3.txt
- C:\application2\project\file1.txt
- C:\application2\project\file2.txt
- C:\application2\project\file3.txt
  and so on..

I think I can figure out how to create the directory if I can somehow read the content of the property file in the right order.

I tried this, but I am not getting the expected results:

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1,* delims== " %%A IN (tempForBatch.txt) DO (
IF "%%A"=="app"  set app=%%B
    echo "App is %app%"

IF "%%A"=="proj" set proj=%%B
    echo "Proj is %proj%"


IF "%%A"=="file"  set file=%%B
echo "File is %file%"
)
```

But I get this instead:
    "App is application"
    "Proj is project"
    "File is file1.txt"
    "App is application"
    "Proj is project"
    "File is file1.txt"
    "App is application"
    "Proj is project"
    "File is file1.txt"
    "App is application"
    "Proj is project"
    "File is file1.txt"
    "App is application"
    "Proj is project"
    "File is file1.txt"

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks for taking the time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (tempForBatch.txt) DO (
    IF /i "%%a"=="app" (
        SET "app=%%b"
    ) ELSE (
        IF /i "%%a"=="proj" (
            SET "proj=%%b"
        ) ELSE (
            IF /i "%%a"=="file" (
                SET "file=%%b"
            ) ELSE (
                SET "file=%%a"
            )
            SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
            ECHO "\!app!\!proj!\!file!"
            ENDLOCAL
        )
    )
)
```

---

```
"\application\project\file1.txt"
"\application\project\file2.txt"
"\application\project\file3.txt"
"\application2\project2\file1.txt"
"\application2\project2\file2.txt"
"\application2\project2\file3.txt"
```

Comment: You are a Genius My friend and a life-saver!